# Declare multiple variables with zero in one line

Tags: vba, excel

In an old macro I declare many variables in one line like

```
Dim Jan_Bnm, Feb_Bnm, Mar_Bnm, Apr_Bnm, Mai_Bnm, Jun_Bnm, Jul_Bnm, Aug_Bnm, Sep_Bnm, Okt_Bnm, Nov_Bnm, Dez_Bnm
```

With this variables I make some calculations like

```
Jan_Bnm = Jan_Bnm + 1 
'e.g. empty = empty + 1 -> 1
```

Now I have the problem if the macro runs twice the old value is still stored

```
Jan_Bnm = Jan_Bnm + 1 
'1 = 1 + 1 -> 2
```

So all my values are doubled.

Is it possible to set all variables by declaration to zero so that I don't have to set every (some hundreds) variable manualy?

Comment: You're probably declaring them out of the routine, if you want them to be "new" at every run you should declare them inside.

Comment: P.s. if you have hundreds of "month" variables, how about re-factoring a bit your code? You might create a collection for example.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thanks for your answer. Yes they are declared outside. The problem was that my sub was too big (excel crushed) so I had to break it into two parts and I need to share them for both subs. The "month" variables are named not as in my example, they have more criteria so unfortunately it's hard to refactore the code

Comment: If you declare them outside, it is _expected_ they keep their own value over multiple executions. You may either pass the variable as parameters into the second sub, or re-set them to 0 _inside_ the first routine. But again, I'm sure that it's worthy you take some time to re-factor your code and use collections instead of single variables :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ just another idea, is there an opinion to loop throw the variables and set them to zero? Something like `foreach variable test in module` -> `if test.name like "*BnM* Then test.value = 0`?

Comment: Even in that case, you will need first to store all the variables in a collection because you cannot work with variable names as if they were strings; then of course, you could loop through them with a simple `For Each var In myCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current situation is the following:

```
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
Sub proc1()

End Sub
Sub proc2()

End Sub
```

The first way to avoid a, b and c still have a value when running proc1() the second time is to re-initialize them on proc1():

```
Sub proc1()
     a = 0
     b = 0 
     c = 0
     'rest of the code
End Sub
```

Another way, you could pass the variables as parameters and declare them only on proc1():

```
 Sub proc1()
      Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
      'rest of the code
      proc2 a,b,c
 End Sub
 Sub proc2(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, ByVal c As Long)

 End Sub
```

Or, finally, you might think about working with a collection rather than with N variables. Example:

```
Dim myVars As New Collection
myVars.Add a
myVars.Add b
myVars.Add c
```

So now you will be able to reinitialize the variables as follows:

```
For j = 1 To myVars.Count
    myVars(j) = 0
Next j
```

And what I said for the N variables (public declaration or private declaration + re-initialization) is applicable to the collection as well, but only once instead of N times (that's why I think it would simplify).