# Excel VBA Set all Collection variables == 1

Tags: vba, excel, collections

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472739/declare-multiple-variables-with-zero-in-one-line) I am trying to set all my variables equal to 1 with a collection. I declared the collection inside one of my Sub Procedures?

```
Public lCol As Long, lRow As Long, rr As Long, cRow As Long, cCol As Long, jj As Long

Dim myVars As New Collection
myVars.Add lRow
myVars.Add lCol
myVars.Add cRow


myVars.Add cCol
myVars.Add rr


For jj = 1 To myVars.Count
    myVars(jj) = 1
Next jj
```

I am receiving an

> Object Required error

on line `myVars(jj) = 1`

Comment: Please read [Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/395dc977(v=vs.100).aspx) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Link provided is for .net. E.g. [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/#Accessing_Items_of_a_Collection) is page about VBA Collections.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot change collection items this way. If you want change item, you must delete it and add a new.